# Is there a way to use Yard Markup with RDoc in a Gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc, yard, gemspecs

The exact question is: How can I instruct `gem` to generate my documentation with Yard. The old way using `#has_rdoc` doesn't function any more. I cannot find the method to do it using metadata in newer GemSpec versions. I would prefer using Yard over TomDoc, but Yard doesn't play for now well with the installation routines.